# How to keep marker size increased all the time cursor is inside

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts chart representing some kind of a bar control. It is defined the following way:

```
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
      credits: {enabled: false},
      chart: {
         renderTo: container,
         type: 'column'
      },
      legend: { enabled : false },
      title: {
         text: title
      },
      xAxis: {
         title: {
            enabled: false,
         },
        min: -500,
        max: 500
      },
      yAxis: {
        enabled: false,
        title: { 
            enabled: false
            },
        labels: { 
            enabled: false
            },
        gridLineWidth: 0
      },
      tooltip: {
         formatter: function() {
            return this.x + ' MW';
         },
        style: {
            fontSize: '8px',
            padding: '0px'
        },
        hideDelay: 200
      },
      plotOptions: {
         scatter: {
            marker: {
                radius: 4,
                lineWidth: 0,
                fillColor: color,
            }
        }
      },
      series: [{
         name: '--',
         type: 'scatter',
         data: points,
         color: graphColor_9
      }]
   });
```

and looks approximatively like this:
[image]

When a cursor hovers over a marker it becomes bigger, see the one on the picture, actually there is a cursor over it. But if I continue moving a cursor inside a marker it returns to the original size after some timeout. I would like a marker to stay big all the time while a cursor is inside. Is it possible?

Comment: How to recreate the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/aeaw3aLv/ - I see no issue here. Could you edit the demo to show the problem?

Comment: @KacperMadej Thanks for your answer. Your example is quite close to my code. And I can't see the pb there but it is present in my code. Could be a pb with other js or css, its quite a big and messy site.

Comment: You need to provide a demo with the issue if you want us to help you because right now we are not able to recreate your problem.

Comment: I understand. I hoped this is a standard setting which someone could just know. Otherwise it would be hard to reproduce, can be related to interference with other css classes for example. Currently I just disabled hoveriong over markers.